# Is this possible with Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Date        COL1    COL2    COL3
2017/01/01   123      A       N
2017/01/01   234      A       N
2017/01/01   567      A       Y
2017/01/01   111      B       N
2017/01/02   123      A       Y
2017/01/02   999      A       N
2017/01/02   333      A       Y
2017/01/02   444      B       N
2017/01/02   555      B       Y
```

Desired Output

```
Date        COL2  Count
2017/01/01   A      1
2017/01/01   B      1
2017/01/02   A      0
2017/01/02   B      1
```

Explanation of desired output:

I want to sum the COL1 rows that belongs to a particular group in COL2, and only sum if the value of COL3 is N and subtract if the COL3 is Y.

(It should be a rolling sum, where the current calculation is based on the sum of the previous date and today's date)

I have come up with a python script that first creates a map, the key is the COL2 and the value is a tuple of date and COL1. 
Then the script loops through the entire dataset, and in the process, I add the current row to the map  if its not in the map, if it is in the map, I append.
Then I just loop through the created map and check the size of each entry to come up with the count.

However I would like to learn how to do this using pandas, I have tried using group by and aggregate, but was unable to get the right format.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering, how come in your desired output, value for 2017/01/02 A has 2 as count.

Comment: @KiriteeGak, sorry for the typo. Corrected the desired output.  Add if COL3 is N, subtract if COL3 is Y.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're grouping by both Date and COL2, here's a one liner solution:

**Creating the DataFrame:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017/01/01', '2017/01/01', '2017/01/01', '2017/01/02', '2017/01/02', '2017/01/02'], 
                   'COL1': [123, 234, 135, 123, 135, 246], 
                   'COL2': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'COL3': ['N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y']})
>>> df
    Date        COL1    COL2    COL3
0   2017/01/01  123     A       N
1   2017/01/01  234     A       N
2   2017/01/01  135     B       Y
3   2017/01/02  123     A       N
4   2017/01/02  135     B       N
5   2017/01/02  246     B       Y
```

**One liner code:**

```
>>> df.join(((df.COL3 == 'N')*2 - 1).rename('Count').to_frame()).groupby(['Date','COL2']).Count.sum().groupby(level=[1]).cumsum().reset_index()
        Date    COL2    Count
0   2017/01/01  A       2
1   2017/01/01  B       -1
2   2017/01/02  A       3
3   2017/01/02  B       -1
```

**Explanation:**

I first created another column by deriving the sum value from `COL3`, naming it as `Count`, then proceed to do a groupby `sum` to get the sum for each `Date`, `COL2` combination, then finally a groupby `cumsum` on the level of `COL2` to get the rolling count.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you are solving a different problem here. For example, the desired output would be (First row) . 2017/01/01 A 2 (Second Row) 2017/01/01 B -1 . (Third Row) 2017/01/02 A 3 . (Forth Row) 2017/01/02 B -1.   So basically, for the first row, instead of summing 123+234, I would like to see 2 because they both are "N" and fits to category A.

Comment: Your question actually mentions: "I want to sum the `COL1` rows that belongs to a particular group in `COL2`, and only sum if the value of `COL3` is N and subtract if the `COL3` is Y"; are you saying that you want to +1 to the count if `COL3` is 'N', and -1 to the count if `COL3` is 'Y'?

Comment: It's even easier in that case, you just remove the `df.COL1` part and you'll get the cumulative count

Comment: Yes, so in your example, instead of summing 123 + 234, it would sum 1 + 1 since both are "N" for category(COL2) "A".  That would result in first row to be 2017/01/01 A 2.  Sorry if I didn't make it clear in description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79143/discussion-between-xdg-and-aranelladen).

Answer (score 1):

Solution would be creating a custom aggregator in `pandas` after a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on columns.

```
>> from pandas import DataFrame as df
>>> df_ = df({'col': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'a': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'b': ['N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']})
>> df_
   a  b  col
0  A  N    1
1  A  N    1
2  B  Y    1
3  A  Y    2
4  B  N    2
5  B  Y    2
>> f = lambda a: list(a).count('N')-list(a).count('Y') # custom aggregation after grouping
>> agg_df = df_.groupby(['col', 'a']).agg({'b': f}).reset_index()
>> agg_df
   col  a  b
0    1  A  2
1    1  B -1
2    2  A -1
3    2  B  0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - How would you apply it to timeseries ? Sorry I'm still learning pandas.  For instance, instead of the first row 0 1 A 2, to be 2017/01/01 A 2.

Comment: You have to set the index to date column. But it is not unique in your case. Since you have grouped it by `date` and `COL2`. So the index can be set to these two columns. But anyway the syntax would be like `df.set_index('some_column')`. Check out the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help